# Bash script -e not detecting filename in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filenames

In a BASH script, I'm trying to detect whether a file exists. The filename is in a variable but the -e command seems to be unable to detect the file. The following code always outputs "~/misc/tasks/drupal_backup.sh does not exist"

```
filename="~/misc/tasks/drupal_backup.sh"

if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
  echo "$filename exists"
else 
  echo "$filename does not exist"
fi
```

On the other hand, the following code detects the file correctly:

```
if [ -e ~/misc/tasks/drupal_backup.sh ]; then
  echo "$filename exists"
else 
  echo "$filename does not exist"
fi
```

Why would this be? How can I get it to detect the file when the filename is in a variable?

Comment: I consider the `~` to be a command line convenience which shouldn't be used in scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an interesting one. Substituting `$HOME` for `~` works as does removing the quotes from the assignment.

If you put a `set -x` at the top of that script, you'll see that the version with quotes sets filename to `~/...` which is what's given to `-e`. If you remove the quotes, filename is set to the expanded `/home/somebody/...`. So in the first case, you see:

```
+ [ -e ~/... ]
```

and it doesn't like it. In the second case, you see:

```
+ [ -e /home/somebody/... ]
```

and it *does* work.

If you do it without the variable, you see:

```
+ [ -e /home/somebody/... ]
```

and, yes, it works.

---

After a bit of investigation, I've found that it's actually the order in which `bash` performs its expansions. From the bash man page:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command  substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

That's why it's not working, the variable is substituted *after* the tilde expansion. In other words, at the point where `bash` wants to expand `~`, there isn't one. It's only after variable expansion does the word get changed into `~/...` and there will be no tilde expansion after that.

One thing you *could* do is to change your `if` statement to:

```
if [[ -e $(eval echo $filename) ]]; then
```

This will evaluate the $filename argument twice. The first time (with `eval`), there will be no `~` during the tilde expansion phase but `$filename` will be changed to `~/...` during the variable expansion phase.

Then, on the second evaluation (the one being done as part of the `if` itself), the `~` will be there during the tilde expansion phase.

I've tested that on my `.profile` file and it seems to work, I suggest you confirm in your particular case.

Comment: It should be noted that you should never use `eval`. `~` is a nice abbreviation for the interactive mode, but should be avioded in scripts for exactly this reason. A lot of init scripts contain something like `[ -r ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile`, and I don't know whether this works if the home directory contains spaces. Better is to use $HOME and quote all variables: `filename="$HOME/misc/tasks/drupal_backup.sh"`. In this case, the quoting is not required, but it's not harmful and it's easier to simply quote everything unless you know exactly where you can leave out the quotes.

Comment: @Phillipp, if you're going to make a blanket statement like "you should never use eval" in a meritocracy, you might want to think about backing it up with your reasoning :-)

Comment: "[breaks] if the home directory contains spaces" -Phillipp, looks like a reason to me and a correct one at that. Multiple `eval` passes are to be avoided because they require as much analysis as your answer did which will still break where filename is `"~/my file"`.

Comment: @msw et al, eval doesn't break with spaces in the home directory. You can do: `filename="~/xyz"` followed by `HOME="a b c" eval echo $filename` and it will successfully output `a b c/xyz` as expected. Now `-e` might break but that's then a simple matter of using `"$(eval echo $filename)"` to ensure it's quoted.